# How do I change column type in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to rake the db:migrations into my heorku instance and I get an error.  The FAQ described my error as below:

> Cannot change column type
>
> Example: PGError: ERROR: column
>   “verified_at” cannot be cast to type
>   “date”
>
> Cause: PostgreSQL doesn’t know how to
>   cast all the rows in that table to the
>   specified type. Most likely it means
>   you have an integer or a string in
>   that column.
>
> Solution: Inspect your records and
>   make sure they can be converted to the
>   new type. Sometimes it’s easier to
>   just avoid using change_column,
>   renaming/creating a new column
>   instead.

How do I change this migration now.  This is the problem that I have.  For my Contacts table, I created the following:

```
  t.string :date_entered
```

In a later migration, I do the following:

```
 change_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date
```

This change_column appears to be the problem.

Should I...change by hand that migration?  Is there a way I can clean the data in my tables (I didn't know Heroku would recognize the data in the table because I'm doing a rake).

I obviously need to change this value and it is used throughout my application.  Thanks.

**This is what I am trying...thoughts?**

```
def self.up
  #change_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date
  #this fails in postgres, so trying the same outcome 

  rename_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date_entered_old
  add_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date
  remove_column :contacts, :date_entered_old
end

def self.down
  add_column :contacts, :date_entered_old
  remove_column :contacts, :date_entered
  rename_column :contacts, :date_entered_old, :date_entered
end
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do the following:

1. rename the column A
2. create the new column B as date
3. move the data from A to B
4. remove A

In other words

```
def self.up
  rename_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date_entered_string
  add_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date

  Contact.reset_column_information
  Contact.find_each { |c| c.update_attribute(:date_entered, c.date_entered_string) } 
  remove_column :contacts, :date_entered_string
end
```

Comment: +1 for #reset_column_information, which I had never seen before. That looks like it would be handy in those very rare times when it's needed.

Comment: If you have a lot of data the update_attribute loop can take a long time. Its much faster to run this raw sql statement that does it all at once.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update table set new_column =old_column");`

If the old value needs a cast no problem either, use postgres cast in the update call.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified and tested version of Simone Carletti's solution

```
class ModifyContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date_entered_string
    add_column :contacts, :date_entered, :date

    Contact.reset_column_information
    Contact.find(:all).each { |contact| contact.update_attribute(:date_entered, contact.date_entered_string) }
    remove_column :contacts, :date_entered_string
  end
end
```

Comment: You do want that `find_each` though. Your version will read the whole table into memory, whereas find_each will get some number of rows at the time.