# rails object.association.count postgres error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I just changed my DB from mysql to postgres and I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...ELECT COUNT(*) FROM "agents"  WHERE "agents"."client_id" = 1
```

when doing

```
client.agents.count
```

I have a Data is structured as follows: Clients have several Agents, and can only add more Agents if `agents.count < X`, so I'm using something like `client.agents.count` to retrieve this value and compare, but I'm getting that error. Do I need to use manual sql to get this done? Or am I missing something stupid?

Thank you for your comments

MODEL INFO

```
class Agent < User

  belongs_to :client
  attr_accessible :client_id

  validates :client_id, presence: true


end

class Client < User
  attr_accessible :appId, :expire_date, :legacy, :url, :plan_id, :chat_window_color, :chat_head_color, :chat_box_container_color, :chat_box_color, :tab_message, :greeting, :please_wait_message, :send_message_button, :comments_label, :offline_message

  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :agents, :dependent => :destroy

  has_secure_password

  after_initialize :init

  #omited validations

  private
  #BEGIN PRIVATE METHODS
end
```

Both inherit from user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :updating_password

  has_secure_password

  before_save { self.email.downcase! }

  #the controller must set updating_password to FALSE to avoid validation
  def should_update_password?
    updating_password || new_record?    
  end

end
```

Comment: Please show the code you have in `app/models/agent.rb` and `app/models/client.rb`

Comment: Then the controller code that is doing the above.

Comment: We can't fix the issue until we see the actual code that's causing it.

Comment: Updated my question to show the Agent/Client/User models, thanks

Comment: The issue was not in a controller, it was in a view on the client's profile, it was `@client.agents.count` @michael-durrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue, the column client_id is a varchar and mysql allowed this but postgres complained about the different datatypes. Got a mgiration working by doing something like this:

```
def up
  rename_column :agents, :client_id, :client_id_old
  add_column :agents, :client_id, :integer
  Agent.reset_column_information
  Agent.find_each { |c| c.update_attribute(:client_id, c.client_id_old) } 
  remove_column :agents, :client_id_old
end
```

From this link [How do I change column type in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075920/how-do-i-change-column-type-in-heroku).

---

To avoid the issues when changing datatypes in postgres directly with `change_column`. Hope this helps someone else