# Replacing values of a column in a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a column called "`p_type`" which is string, since I thought to have types `A`, `B` and `C` as strings

now I realize that it is better to have that as a `bitmask` so I can have `A` and `C` together.

If I do

```
change_column :cars, :p_type, :integer
```

I will either lose all my existing p_type data or something will go horribly wrong and migration will distort the data somehow ( I am afraid to try)

Is there a way to change the column type to :`integer` and have some kind of function in the migration file that will do

```
if A
 p_type = 1
elsif B
 p_type = 2
elsif C
 p_type = 4
end
```

so the migration would change the data type and the data itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with [How do I change column type in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075920/how-do-i-change-column-type-in-heroku)

```
rename_column :cars, :p_type , :p_type_string
add_column :cars, :p_type , :integer
Car.reset_column_information
Car.find_each { |c| c.update_attribute(:p_type , c.p_type_string) } 
remove_column :cars, :p_type_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run one rake task first to update the p_type column,

```
Model_name.each { |obj|
if obj.p_type == "A"
 p_type = "1"
elsif obj.p_type == "B"
 p_type = "2"
elsif obj.p_type == "C"
 p_type = "4"
end
obj.save
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: You will either have to do this from the rails console (rails c -e production) or from a migration. I'm not sure creating a new rake task for a data migration is a good choice.